# ssh: connect to host 18.217.164.53 port 22: Operation timed out

Tags: server, ssh, ufw

I have read every related questions but could not find solution yet. I am still new to AWS but managed to set up an instance and deploy my website. My `uwf status` was inactive so I hit `sudo ufw enable` but I forgot to hit `sudo ufw allow ssh` and now I can not use ssh when I press `ssh -i /Users/xyz/files/webshop.pem ubuntu@xx.xxx.xxx.xx` in my mac terminal. Is there any rapid way to manage the issue without creating a new instance on AWS?

Any help would be greatly appreciated (I have to demo my applcation on Thursady).

Comment: You locked your door, then closed the locked door behind you without a key in your pocket. No, there is no easy way to open the locked door now using ssh. If there were, it wouldn't be a useful lock.

Comment: Thanks @user535733. So better if I delete and create a new instance? No any way to solv it with aws maybe?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with AWS tools to say. (If I were, I'd have written an answer). I was only discussing the dismal possibility of an SSH-based solution.

Comment: Understood. Now I learnt this for good...

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11776183/10266059 which addresses exactly this use case, where SSH access is no longer available.